# sql query to display unavailable number?

Tags: sql

i have some list of numbers with me, i want to check that numbers in a specified table available or not, if any number is not available in the table from the  list of given numbers, then that unavailable number need to be display

Comment: It's a tad hard to understand the question as it's currently worded, at least for me. Could you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for that data? Also, what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: select account from table where account in (1,2,3,4,5)                                if in the above list 4 is not there in the table, it has to display

4     in sql server 2008

Comment: my actual query is " select count(*) from table where name in (a,b,c,d)"  if all names are there in the table it displays count as 4. if any name not there in the table it displays 3 or 2 or 1 or 0. but i need to display the specific name which are not there in table from the list of given names.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt sure that i understad your query correctly,
but it seems you mean somthing like this:

```
select *   
from TABLE_NAME t  
where t.COLUMN_NAME not in (1,2,3.... (#your list values#))
```

Comment: my actual query is " select count(*) from table where name in (a,b,c,d)"  if all names are there in the table it displays count as 4. if any name not there in the table it displays 3 or 2 or 1 or 0. but i need to display the specific name which are not there in table from the list of given names.

Comment: No problem, Only need to display the field value instead of the count, Like this: select t.COLUMN_NAME  
from TABLE_NAME t  
where t.COLUMN_NAME not in (1,2,3.... (#your list values#))

Comment: nah,man. if you column_name include 1,2,8,9 and the list only have 1,2,3. you will display 8,9. I don't think that's what Kumar want, he want the 3

Comment: Ahhha, Ok, Try perform the opposite: SELECT  * FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS X(a) where X.a not in YOUR_TABLE.YOUR_COLUMN

Answer (score 0):

save the list of number first:

```
   Create table list(id int);
   insert into list(id)values(1);
   insert into list(id)values(2);
   insert into list(id)values(3);
   insert into list(id)values(4);
```

Create sample table

```
   Create table chck_list(id int,name varchar2(10));
   insert into chck_list(id,name)values(1,'Micheal');
   insert into chck_list(id,name)values(2,'John');
   insert into chck_list(id,name)values(8,'Jack');
```

Query to check if there are id in list not showed in chck_list

```
   select list.id 
     from list lst
    where not exists(select 1 from chck_list chck where chck.id=lst.id)
```

Result

```
   =========================
       id
   =========================
       3
       4
```

Comment: my actual query is " select count(*) from table where name in (a,b,c,d)"  if all names are there in the table it displays count as 4. if any name not there in the table it displays 3 or 2 or 1 or 0. but i need to display the specific name which are not there in table from the list of given names.